# How do I give each tab opened by a {Task} a custom name?

Tags: conemu

I have a ConEmu [{Task}](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Settings#Tasks) that opens several tabs, each to a different directory. The trouble is, these tabs all have the same name and are hard to tell apart. I know I can rename each tab by right-clicking it and selecting **rename***, but is there a way of renaming each one automatically via the task configuration?

It would be super-handy being able to:

a) specify a custom title;
b) specify a variable title using the current directory.

(*what is the <kbd>Apps</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut, btw? I've never come across the <kbd>Apps</kbd> key before.)

Comment: WinUser.h -> #define `VK_APPS` 0x5D. May be you come across this as `Menu`? :-P

Comment: Provide a contents of your {Task}

Comment: Here's is the task config: http://i.imgur.com/dNr2M.png and here is what it looks like when I launch it from the ConEmu menu: http://i.imgur.com/RjIp3.png

Comment: Re. `Menu` I don't have one of those either. I've just got a standard UK keyboard (from Dell). EDIT: yes I do! It's the key next to the right Ctrl.

Comment: So, `Apps` is found? And how it is named? ;)

Comment: b) did you mean synchronous changing of tab title with `cd` in tcc?

Comment: The `Apps` key has a menu symbol on it. Take a look: http://www.buypcsupplies.com/images/cat/38550_xlargenss_ndo4190.jpg

Comment: b) yes, so that it can show the current directory. Like `prompt $p` but truncating from the left if the path gets too long to fit in the tab.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1) Modify contents of your task. Example:

```
>cmd /c RenameTab "Tab1" & tcc cdd C:\temp
cmd /k RenameTab "Tab2" & cd /d D:\
cmd /c RenameTab "Tab3" & stermc charlesr ...
```

And so on... Supposing, that %ConEmuBaseDir% exists in %PATH%. This can be done automatically with last ConEmu versions (option on `ComSpec` settings page).

More short and preferable alternative is available in build 121109 or higher

```
>tcc cdd C:\temp "-new_console:t:Tab1"
cmd /k cd D:\ "-new_console:t:Tab2"
stermc charles "-new_console:t:Tab3"
```

2) As for `CD` in title, you may use usual method. This works for `cmd` and `tcc` consoles. Example:

```
tcc prompt $E]2;"$P"$E\$P$G & cdd D:\
cmd prompt $E]2;"$P"$E\$P$G & cd /d D:\
```

**Don't** use `1` and `2` simultaneously. `RenameTab` has precedence!

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it was possible - thank you. Having said that, 2) isn't working for me - it doesn't change the tab name. Could you possibly show what it should look like in your {Tasks} config?

Comment: Note! `prompt $E]2;"$P"$E\$P$G` change console title, not rename tab. Rename tab has priority. http://i.imgur.com/UCl3R.png http://i.imgur.com/A0WwJ.png

Comment: New switch introduced, answer updated.

Comment: I added this to my powershell profile, see here: https://github.com/majkinetor/powershell_profile.d/blob/master/10_prompt.ps1#L11

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

`title your-desired-tab-name`

I tried it on my conemu and it works just fine. Just input those commands on the command line of conemu.